# Newbie ask Swap Value: How much Swap do I have?

Tags: swap

When looking vmstat, this is what I got:

`procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------

 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st

 1  0      0   2872      0      0    0    0     8    17    0   14  3  1 94  2  0`


the `cache` is `0`. I have no idea how much the whole swap I have.

But when not enough RAM (256 MB), the swap will be used and look like below:

`procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------

 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st

 3  1   2468      0      0      0    0    0     8    17    0   16  3  1 94  2  0`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is on Linux - `free -m` will show you how much memory/swap you have in MB. Or `cat /proc/meminfo`

Answer (score 2):

To see information about swap files currently in use on Linux:

> cat /proc/swaps

or refer to swap information in meminfo for less detail:

> cat /proc/meminfo | grep Swap

Answer (score 1):

One of the header lines in `top` will be Swap info, and it's very clearly broken down.

This also has the advantage of working on any platform where `top` is installed (Every Linux/BSD I know of. Most Solaris, AIX & HP-UX machines (if it didn't come with the system some admin usually got around to installing it)).

Comment: (I got from top) Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any swap configured (or it's not attached/enabled) -- that's a bit unusual but not impossible.  Are there any lines in /etc/fstab with type "swap"? If so try "swapon -a" (as root) & the system will try to enable them.

Comment: True that top is almost everywhere, but I was surprised to find it missing on Tru64. Not that anyone cares about that any more...

Comment: `htop` is a more friendly version. :)

Comment: @EricR - True, but `htop` isn't everywhere (for that matter neither is `top`, but you know it will be there on the systems I listed).  I suppose the *truly* portable alternative is `swapinfo`, but that requires you to do your own math for totals if you have more than one swap partition - `top` does it for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Many systems have some command to detail this information outright: the commands are usually one of: `swap` or `swapinfo` or `swapon` (with appropriate option). Look up the man pages for these commands to find the specific information.

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
mkswap /path/to/dev
```

Then run

```
swapon -a
```